# GWT 2.7 - Xmx with localWorkers flag and <collapse-all-properties />

Tags: gwt, gwt-2.7

Query 1 - If we have set -Xmx12288m in extraJvmArgs and set localWorkers flag to 4. Will this allot 12Gigs to each thread or split the 12 gigs into 3gigs each for the 4 threads?

Query 2 - If we use `<collapse-all-properties />` then will the compiler still use 4 threads from localWorkers for single permutation? ( Not likely as per documentation )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) it's the maximum heap space so it's split over your threads, on a per need basis (not necessarily 3/3/3/3)

2) not sure, suggest you try it. `collapse-all-properties` will produce a single output file, but I'm not sure if that means that only single permutation is computed (skipping the need for localWorkers) or that still several permutations are computed but merged into one file. Any case, if `localWorkers=4` won't help, it won't hurt either.

Comment: 2) is correct - the forked threads or processes are only created to do the permutation work, so avoiding those threads by using only one permutation is a win either way.